# fcm not working in release mode from play store kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FCM notifications setup on my app. It works both debug and release modes.

When I create a release apk and test it on my phone, notifications work. But when I upload an appbundle to the play store, the version I download from the play store has notifications not working. The getToken method returns null, any ideas on why this could be the case?